# The proof of $rank(M(G))=n-1$ when $G$ is a bipartite graph of order $n$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph of order $n$. How can I prove "If $G$ is a bipartite graph, then $rank (M(G))=n-1$?

where $M(G)$ is the incidence matrix of $G$.

Comment: Context is not difficult to provide for a math problem you are genuinely interested in.  A good Question will require research effort before posting.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column space is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with basis $\{\vec{e_i}| i\in A\}\cup \{\vec{e_j}| j\in B\}$, where $A,B$ are the independent sets of vertices coming from the bipartion.

As the graph is connected, the column space contains $\vec{e_i}-\vec{e_k}$ when $i,k\in A$ and $\vec{e_j}-\vec{e_l}$ when $j,l\in B$ and $\vec{e_i} +\vec{e_j}$ when $i\in A,j\in B$.

Thus the column space is the codimension $1$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, consisting of vectors: $$\sum_{i\in A}\lambda_i \vec{e_i}+\sum_{j\in B}\mu_j \vec{e_j},$$ which satisfy the single constraint:
$$\sum_{i\in A}\lambda_i =\sum_{j\in B}\mu_j.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.